# Solve $\frac {2 \tan x}{1-\tan^2x} = \sin^22x$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve this trigonometric equation?

$$\frac {2 \tan x}{1-\tan^2x} = \sin^22x$$

I got to this stage: $$\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x} = \sin^22x$$

Is it a dead end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\tan (x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$,

$$\frac {2 \tan x}{1-\tan^2x}=\tan 2x=\sin 2x\sec 2x$$

$$\sin 2x\sec 2x=\sin^22x$$

$$\sin 2x\big(\frac{1}{\cos 2x}-\sin 2x\big)=0$$

So either $\sin2x=0$ or $\frac{1}{\cos 2x}=\sin 2x$
You can solve first one easily.

For second one,
$$\sin 2x\cos 2x=1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sin 4x=1$$
$$\sin 4x=2$$
which is not possible because $-1\le \sin\theta\le 1$

So only the solutions of first equation satisfy the given equation.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is $\sec$ because I never learned it

Comment: $sec(x)=\frac{1}{cos(x)}$

Comment: Is there any way in the world to do this equation without $\sec$?

Comment: Please see the edited answer if you are facing difficulties

Comment: Why $\frac {2 \tan x}{1-\tan^2x}=\tan 2x$ is it identity?

Comment: You should know that $\tan (x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$. Put x=y to get the relation.

Comment: Thanks, is good to know new things :)

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much, solved it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to rewrite it in the following way. $$0=\sin^2(2x)-\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$$
$$0 = \sin(2x) \cdot \left[\sin(2x)-\frac{1}{\cos(2x)}\right]$$
$$0= \sin(2x) \cdot \frac{\sin(2x)\cdot \cos(2x)-1}{\cos(2x)}$$ 
Then use $\sin(2x) \cdot \cos(2x) = \frac{\sin(4x)}{2}$.

Comment: You can produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$ by typing \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x, respectively, in math mode.

Comment: Thank you, i always forget that :). Not used to latex notation that much :D.